# NPM Install Error / Permissions

Tags: npm, terminal

Using MacOSX Terminal trying to install NPM and getting the following errors. I have changed the permissions but still getting this error. Can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I have npm working fine in another directory project but can't get it to run in this one. Even though it says to run command as root/administrator, I get the same error when using sudo. Have not had luck trying to change permission for directories, they are all set with the right permissions. What is causing this error?

```
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:reactjs daniel$ npm install
npm ERR! path /Users/daniel/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6915147f
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/daniel/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6915147f'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/daniel/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6915147f'
npm ERR!   cause: 
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/daniel/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6915147f'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!      path: '/Users/daniel/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6915147f' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir \'/Users/daniel/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6915147f\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/daniel/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-6915147f' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/daniel/.npm/_logs/2018-03-31T18_04_44_157Z-debug.log
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:reactjs daniel$
```

When I use sudo, I get a similar error:

```
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:reactjs daniel$ sudo npm install
Password:
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master git://github.com/thrivingkings/animo.js.git /Users/daniel/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-fbfd8ddc
npm ERR! /Users/daniel/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-fbfd8ddc/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/daniel/.npm/_logs/2018-03-31T18_13_00_240Z-debug.log
Daniels-MacBook-Pro:reactjs daniel$
```

Comment: Try to update npm to latest version, it had several issues like that you described

Comment: It looks like you are trying to install a dependency that is either deleted or don't have public access. Can u show your list of dependencies from package.json?

Comment: also, see the detail of error in your "/Users/daniel/.npm/_logs/2018-03-31T18_13_00_240Z-debug.log" file.